# Changing MSWord floating objects to inline objects without changing page layout

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Is there any way of changing all floating objects in a document, without changing their size or position on the page? Using:

```
shape.WrapFormat.Type = Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapInline;
```

or 
    shape.ConvertToInlineShape()

can result in shifted objects, especially if the page is split into two columns and if there are floating objects before/after the target object. I have tested this with images and textboxes containing images and text.

Comment: Typically the layout is very likely to change, because inline images are less flexible regarding the layout options. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: This is needed for an addin that can't work with floating objects, and so I need to change all objects to inline (while maintaining the original layout). I hoped that a workaround might exist.